# Как указать путь к библиотеке Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Через pip установил библиотеку pygame. Но про вводе кода import pygame выдает ошибку не найдена библиотека, хотя введя в терминал help('modules') видно что библиотека установлена. Пробовал в Visual Studio, PyCharm и Idle

Comment: _Но про вводе кода import pygame выдает ошибку_ - кто именно выдает ошибку? Ошибка при запуске или просто в редакторе подсвечивается?

Comment: Можно долго гадать на кофейной гуще. Traceback в студию.

Answer (score -1):

Не знаю что у тебя за код, но, возможно у тебя не указана функция `pygame.init()` после импорта функций, возможно у тебя не создано графическое окно, возможно у тебя не указан сам цикл программы, возможно нету функции `pygame.quit()` в конце цикла, сам я не писал, но вот [ссылка](https://python-course.readthedocs.io/projects/elementary/en/latest/lessons/18-pygame.html) от куда взял возможные проблем:

Comment: Как то, что вы описали связано с вопросом?