# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AppKit'

Tags: python, pip

Установил через pip AppKit на python 3.12, но почему-то этот модуль не обнаружен

Comment: На английском СО советуют ещё поставить `pip install -U PyObjC`

Comment: возможно Вам поможет этот ответ - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1572099/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b5-python/1572106#1572106

Comment: `pip list` please.
А заодно уж и `pip3 list`